# What mark-up would be semantically correct to make this calculator in HTML5?

Tags: html, css

What mark-up would be semantically correct to make this calculator in HTML5, CSS?

[image]

Comment: Technically the buttons are inputs.

Comment: I have a green hooded sweatshirt. My sweatshirt is green and has a hood. Which of these two sentences is semantically correct? Both. They mean the same thing. HTML is the same way. Multiple ways of approaching the same meaning.

Comment: This to me is a classic ***"Can someone please make this for me in HTML5 and CSS3"***, And I did.. and mine is awesome ;) however still shows no effort.

Comment: @rlemon - I'm not asking to make it. I'm just asking which HTML tag I should choose that

Comment: <div>, <table>, <span>, <ul>, ect...

Answer (score 1):

CSS doesn't have semantics, just HTML.

There are many ways of writing the markup for something as simple as a calculator.

Using `input:button` elements could work, or `button` elements, or `a[href="#some-action"]` elements. You could use `div` elements with `onclick` handlers added via JavaScript, and as long as you provided enough correct information it would be semantically valid.

I could mark up the calculator as:

```
<div class="calculator">
    <div class="output">
        <span>0</span>
    </div>
    <div class="input">
        <div class="memory">
            <a href="#memory-clear" class="memory-clear">MC</a>
            <a href="#memory-add" class="memory-add">M+</a>
            <a href="#memory-subtract" class="memory-subtract">M-</a>
            <a href="#memory-recall" class="memory-recall">MR</a>
        </div>
        <div class="operators">
            <a href="#cancel" class="cancel">C</a>
            <a href="#negate" class="negate">&plusmn;</a>
            <a href="#divide" class="divide">&divide;</a>
            <a href="#multiply" class="multiply">&times;</a>
            <a href="#subtract" class="subtract">&minus;</a>
            <a href="#add" class="add">+</a>
            <a href="#equals" class="equals">=</a>
        </div>
        <div class="numbers">
            <a href="#num-9" class="number number-9">9</a>
            <a href="#num-8" class="number number-8">8</a>
            <a href="#num-7" class="number number-7">7</a>
            <a href="#num-6" class="number number-6">6</a>
            <a href="#num-5" class="number number-5">5</a>
            <a href="#num-4" class="number number-4">4</a>
            <a href="#num-3" class="number number-3">3</a>
            <a href="#num-2" class="number number-2">2</a>
            <a href="#num-1" class="number number-1">1</a>
            <a href="#num-0" class="number number-0">0</a>
            <a href="#decimal" class="decimal">.</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I don't think it matters a great deal, since you're not marking up a document, but an app with rich functionality, it's going to be completely dependent on JavaScript anyway.

Though if forced to choose, I'd go with `<input type="button" />` instead of `<input type="submit" />` since you're not technically submitting a form. Or perhaps go with `<button></button>` element. Your number display will be `<input type="text" />` as I would encourage direct input via the keyboard/keypad. You could use `<input type="number" />` but some browsers such as Opera will render up/down arrows to the right of the input which would look funny on a calculator, not sure if these can be styled away, so use type="text" with JavaScript to reject non-numeric characters.

To sum up, I wouldn't obsessed over it too much, HTML5 doesn't have anything specific for this sort of thing in terms of new elements.

Comment: HTML5 has the `<output>` element which could be used for the display, but you make a good point about allowing direct input via the keyboard/keypad.

Comment: Semantics are *more* important in apps because they're what guide accessibility.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone has already mentioned that there are multiple *valid ways* to do this..

Here is my spin on it.

```
<div class="calc">
    <div class="display">0</div>

    <div class="btn">MC</div>
    <div class="btn">M+</div>
    <div class="btn">M-</div>
    <div class="btn">MR</div>

    <div class="btn">C</div>
    <div class="btn">±</div>
    <div class="btn">÷</div>
    <div class="btn">x</div>

    <div class="btn">7</div>
    <div class="btn">8</div>
    <div class="btn">9</div>
    <div class="btn">-</div>

    <div class="btn">4</div>
    <div class="btn">5</div>
    <div class="btn">6</div>
    <div class="btn">+</div>

    <div class="btn">7</div>
    <div class="btn">8</div>
    <div class="btn">9</div>
    <div class="btn">-</div>

    <div class="btn">1</div>
    <div class="btn">2</div>
    <div class="btn">3</div>
    <div class="btn tall">=</div>

    <div class="btn wide">0</div>
    <div class="btn">.</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.calc {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 6px solid #009;
  width: 128px;
  padding: 12px 0px 2px 0px;
  background-color: #00a;
}
.display {
 width: 124px;
 background-color: #666;
 text-align: right;
}
.display:before {
 position: absolute;
 top: 7px;
 left: 7px;
 content: 'rlemon calc';
 font-size: 50%;
 color: #fff;
}
.display, .btn {
 height: 20px;
 margin: 1px;
 padding: 3px 1px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
 -moz-border-radius: 4px;
 border-radius: 4px;   
}
.btn {
 float: left;
 width: 28px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #999;
}
.wide {
 width: 60px;
}
.tall {
 height: 48px;
 float: right;
}
```

[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/sS4V8/6/) *CSS may require some optimization*

Comment: to work with the elements I wouldn't use id's, I would utilize the *dataset* and add `data-btn="+"` then in the javascript you can access it using `element.dataset.btn;`